# What's the plural of project in-charge?

Tags: sentence-construction, indian-english

**Check this scenario -**

> "*There's a bug in software your company built.*" 
> "*Oh, I'm so sorry. You may meet the project in-charge (say he's Jack) for that."*

**The question now:**

> What if there are many people *in-charge*. Say, Jack, Jill, Johny and Michael?
>
> "*There's a bug in software your company built.*" 
> "*Oh, I'm so sorry. You may meet the **project in-charges** for that."* - is certainly incorrect.

If anyone answers that *in-charge* is **always one person**, the question's solved!

Note: *project in-charge* is a noun in this case.

Comment: Project in-charge is *not* a name or title of a person.  You may mean *Program manager*?

Comment: @Jim No. I did mean a title/post of a person. Now this makes me afraid, whether it exists! In our country, it's way common and used damn frequently.

Comment: For instance (and many more actually) - http://www.linkedin.com/title/project+in+charge/, http://www.itsmyascent.com/job-detail-269542/Tunip%20Agro%20Limited/N/A/Project%20In%20Charge etc.

Comment: I've not seen _in-charge_ used as a title, either, but I believe that it's used in places other than where I live. I think you've pluralized it correctly: _"We'll have to get the in-charges together for a formal meeting."_ Also, no, the problem isn't solved by saying that it's "always one person," because you'd still need to pluralize the word if you are talking about multiple people with that role: _"There will be a special conference for project in-charges next month. As our project in-change, would you like to go?"_

Comment: Ok, well, I'd be likely to suggest, "The management team", or, I suppose, "the in-charge team"

Comment: I think I might avoid that by saying *"the people in charge (of the project)"* instead.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - That might bypass the problem for an instance, but, if _in-charge_ is a common job title, chances are it will need to be pluralized at some time or another. _"We're getting hit hard by retirements this year! We'll need to hire three more in-charges before the end of the summer."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When pluralizing multiple-word terms, we often pluralize the first word, because that is where the noun resides:

- one attorney at law, three attorneys at law
- one mother-in-law, three brothers-in-law
- one ambassador at large, three ambassadors at large

However, if the first word (or words) function as a qualifier, we pluralize the noun at the end:

- one department head, two department heads
- one county deputy sheriff, two county deputy sheriffs
- one Juvenile Firesetter Intervention Specialist, two Juvenile Firesetter Intervention Specialists

In the case of *project in-charge*, *in-charge* is the position title, and *project* is a qualifier; therefore:

- one project in-charge, four project in-charges

As I mentioned in an earlier comment, even if each project has only one in-charge, that won't negate the need for a plural.

> *Our company has five in-charges on the payroll, but only four of them are working as an in-charge right now, because we only have four projects at the moment. However, if we land that contract with Acme Aerospace next month, we'll take Brice off of Thelma's project, and he'll be the in-charge for the Acme project*.

Answer (score 0):

We have *in-laws*, therefore by the same token, I guess we could have *in-charges*.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].

Comment: For in-law, I think we can have only either _ins-laws_ or _in-laws_. The former doesn't seem to stand a chance in this case to be the correct one.